Proving the Existence of a Unique Solution for a Boundary Value Problem with Lipschitz Continuity Condition
We consider the continuous function $h(x, y)$ that satisfies the Lipschitz condition on $[ \alpha, \beta ] \times \mathbb{R}$. If the difference $\beta - \alpha$ is sufficiently small such that
$
\frac{K (\beta - \alpha)^2}{4} < 1
$
where K is the Lipschitz constant, then prove that there exists a unique solution of the BVP
\begin{align*}
y'' + h(x, y) &= 0 \\
y(\alpha) &= 0 \\
y(\beta) &= 0
\end{align*}
I tried to prove that h(x,y) and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x,y)$ are continuous in order to use the existence and uniqueness theorem, but I am stuck on how to use that $\frac{K (\beta - \alpha)^2}{4} < 1$.

Using Green's function
$$
G(x,\xi)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
               \frac{(\beta-x)(\xi-\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}, & \alpha\le \xi\le x\le \beta \\
               \frac{(x-\alpha)(\beta-\xi)}{\beta-\alpha}, & \alpha \le x \le \xi \le \beta
               \end{array} \right.,
$$
the BVP $(\ast)$ $y''+h(x,y)=0$, $y(\alpha)=y(\beta)=0$ is equivalent to the fixed point equation
$$
y(x)= (Ty)(x):= \int_\alpha^\beta G(x,\xi) h(\xi,y(\xi))d\xi
$$
in $C([\alpha,\beta],\mathbb{R})$. Check that $0 \le G(x,\xi)\le (\beta-\alpha)/4$ and
$$
\int_\alpha^\beta G(x,\xi)d\xi =\frac{1}{2}(x-\alpha)(\beta-x) \le \frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{8}\quad (x\in [\alpha,\beta]).
$$
Consider the Banach space $C([\alpha,\beta],\mathbb{R})$ endowed with the maximum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. If
$$
|h(x,y_1)-h(x,y_2)| \le K|y_1-y_2| \quad ((x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in 
[\alpha,\beta] \times \mathbb{R}),
$$
then $T: C([\alpha,\beta],\mathbb{R}) \to C([\alpha,\beta],\mathbb{R})$ satisfies
$$
|(Ty_1)(x)-(Ty_2)(x)| \le \int_\alpha^\beta G(x,\xi) K|y_1(\xi)-y_2(\xi)| d\xi \le K\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{8} \|y_1 -y_2\|_\infty 
$$
for $x\in [\alpha,\beta]$, hence
$$
\|Ty_1-Ty_2\|_\infty \le K\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{8} \|y_1 -y_2\|_\infty \quad (y_1,y_2 \in C([\alpha,\beta],\mathbb{R})).
$$
Thus, if
$$
K\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{8} < 1
$$
Banach's FPT proves the existence of a unique solution of $(\ast)$.
The worse condition
$$
K\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{4} < 1,
$$
sometimes found in literature, comes from the worse estimate
$$
\int_\alpha^\beta G(x,\xi) K|y_1(\xi)-y_2(\xi)| d\xi \le K\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{4} \|y_1 -y_2\|_\infty
$$
where $G(x,\xi)\le (\beta-\alpha)/4$ is used. The optimal condition (obtained by a suitable weighted maximum norm and sometimes called "Theorem of Lettenmeyer") is
$$
K\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2} < 1.
$$
Optimality can be seen by the unsolvable BVP $y''+\pi^2 y-1 =0$, $y(0)=y(1)=0$.
